# html5 video playback on iOS (iPhoneX)

Tags: ios, iphone, html, html5-video

**Hey everyone,**

we have a serious issue with a website where we have an html5 video on the landingpage. It's a `muted autoplay` 5second loop that is supposed to play as a background-video on the site.

Now … we have two persons testing it, with the exact same device.
iPhoneX with Google Chrome (caches cleared and tested on both devices with Incognito and without)

On my phone the autplay works just fine. Video plays in the background.

On my collegues iPhoneX (same build, bought at the same date, same iOS version, same Browser (caches cleared)) it does not play automatically. He get's the play-icon.

Any idea why?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

For everyone looking into that. The reason is iOS Low-Power-Mode. in low power mode the videos do not automatically play.